# Updating Two Databases Via A Load Balancer?

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, load-balancing

We have built two servers on Azure each server a copy of the other. With a load balancer which moves from one to the other, if one fails.

We have a self host Git server which runs an Ansible playbook to deploy Docker containers.

Each server has its own Elastic Search Index/database. These are kept up to date with a trigger in the core/main database.

So my question is how do we update both indexes at the same time? Could we route the path `/update` though the load balancer and get to run on both servers?

Thanks,

Comment: You can use logstash which can take one input and send it to multiple output nodes

Comment: Load balancer is a traffic load balancing tool. Wen you connct the backend server, you're establishing one connection with one machine. You cannot deliver one traffic to mulitple backend machines. You'd better update the database one by one. If possible, you can write scripts to do automation.